# How to create native installers using jpackage in maven for each operating system?

Tags: java, maven, build, jpackage

*Jpackage using maven failed with Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin: Unable to resolve project dependencies: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/bin/java"*

I am trying to use jpackage command to generate native installers in maven for Windows, Linux and Mac using Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin.

Link to jpackage maven plugin: https://github.com/Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin (it requires min. version of Maven 3.8.6)

JDK/JRE I am using is Bellsoft LIberica JDK 17.0.6+10 and JRE 17.0.6+10 https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/.

IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Community Edition)

Maven version: 3.9.0

The operating system I am on is Kubuntu 22.10

jpackage-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.akman</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <appversion>${project.version}</appversion>
        <input>${jpackageInputDir}</input>
        <mainjar>${buildDirectory}/mainjar.jar</mainjar>
        <mainclass>${mainClass}</mainclass>
        <icon>${project.basedir}/books256.ico</icon>
        <name>${fn}</name>
        <dest>${jpackageOutputDir}</dest>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jpackagedeblinux</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jpackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <linuxshortcut>true</linuxshortcut>
                <type>DEB</type>
                <toolhome>${jpackageJdkDirLinux}</toolhome>
                <runtimeimage>${jpackageJreDirLinux}</runtimeimage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jpackagewinmsi</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jpackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <type>MSI</type>
                <toolhome>${jpackageJdkDirWin}</toolhome>
                <runtimeimage>${jpackageJreDirWin}</runtimeimage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jpackagepkgmac</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jpackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <type>PKG</type>
                <toolhome>${jpackageJdkDirMac}</toolhome>
                <runtimeimage>${jpackageJreDirMac}</runtimeimage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: removing `<toolHome>` (Path to jdk - actual jdk tools used. If not present, default is used.) and/or `<runtimeImage>` (jre to be copied to resulting installer) parameters does not make a change.

Properties:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.sourceEncoding>UTF-8
        </project.reporting.sourceEncoding>
    <fn>mainjar</fn>
    <mainClass>core.Main</mainClass>
    <buildDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</buildDirectory>
    <jpackageInputDir>${buildDirectory}/jpackage_inputdir</jpackageInputDir>
    <jpackageOutputDir>${buildDirectory}/jpackage_outputdir</jpackageOutputDir>
    <jpackageJreDir>${buildDirectory}/jpackage</jpackageJreDir>
    <jpackageJreDirMac>${jpackageJreDir}/mac</jpackageJreDirMac>
    <jpackageJreDirWin>${jpackageJreDir}/win</jpackageJreDirWin>
    <jpackageJreDirLinux>${jpackageJreDir}/linux</jpackageJreDirLinux>
    <jpackageJdkDirMac>${jpackageJreDir}/jdk-mac</jpackageJdkDirMac>
    <jpackageJdkDirWin>${jpackageJreDir}/jdk-win</jpackageJdkDirWin>
    <jpackageJdkDirLinux>${jpackageJreDir}/jdk-linux</jpackageJdkDirLinux>
</properties>
```

Note: all jres/jdks are present in their respective folders.

The error I get during jpackage goal (full stack trace):

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.akman:jpackage-maven-plugin:0.1.5:jpackage (jpackage deb linux) on project desktop.mainapp: Error: Unable to resolve project dependencies: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/bin/java" (in directory "/tmp/plexus-java_jpms-17951190539128822429"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.akman:jpackage-maven-plugin:0.1.5:jpackage (jpackage deb linux) on project desktop.mainapp: Error: Unable to resolve project dependencies
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error: Unable to resolve project dependencies
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.resolveDependencies (JPackageMojo.java:1330)
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.execute (JPackageMojo.java:1875)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/bin/java" (in directory "/tmp/plexus-java_jpms-17951190539128822429"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.MainClassModuleNameExtractor.extract (MainClassModuleNameExtractor.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths (LocationManager.java:235)
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.resolveDependencies (JPackageMojo.java:1328)
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.execute (JPackageMojo.java:1875)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:314)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:244)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.MainClassModuleNameExtractor.extract (MainClassModuleNameExtractor.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager.resolvePaths (LocationManager.java:235)
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.resolveDependencies (JPackageMojo.java:1328)
    at ru.akman.maven.plugins.jpackage.JPackageMojo.execute (JPackageMojo.java:1875)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:821)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Can someone find out the cause of this error and how to fix it? How to make it work maybe with another plugin or setting? Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin is the only one I find, in which I can define home for java tools, which should allow me to make native runtime images for another operating systems, but as you can see it does not work for some reason.

Comment: you can try [link](https://github.panteleyev.org/jpackage-maven-plugin/examples/executions.html)

Comment: @Sepi Works, but only for platform I am curretly on.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether you run `jpackage` with Maven or standalone. It (currently) does not support building for a different platform: [Application packages must be built on the target platform.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-786E15C0-2CE7-4BDF-9B2F-AC1C57249134:~:text=Application%20packages%20must%20be%20built%20on%20the%20target%20platform.)